# I upgraded my CC programs and now they are no longer on the dock. How to get them there?

Tags: macos

I upgraded my Creative Cloud programs and now they are no longer on the dock. How may I get them there (Photoshop, Illustrator, Muse, etc)

Comment: Thank you, but, I cannot right-click with my Mac mouse. Also I tried dragging the icon to the dock and it just goes back into Applications. – JayeO yesterday

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to put anything in the Dock is just to find it in your Applications folder & drag it there

[image]

it will become a permanent addition.

[image]

You can remove it again by dragging the Dock icon out to the desktop...

[image]

None of this will affect the app itself, only its appearance in the Dock.

Comment: Or, while they are running, right-click on the Dock icon and pin them.

Comment: Thank you, but, I cannot right-click with my Mac mouse. Also I tried dragging the icon to the dock and it just goes back into Applications.